# Is volatile enough in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is my app's start/stop procedure, start/stop code is handled by a single-threaded `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so I'm guaranteed there's only one thread can be active at the same time.

I'm asking about `isRunning` variable. Is making the variable `volatile` enough?
The variable will be accessed (read/modify) from different threads (but only one at the same time!)

```
public final class Work {

    private static final ThreadPoolExecutor processor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
    private static final Runnable startQuery = Work::startProcedure,
            stopQuery = Work::stopProcedure;

    private static boolean isRunning = false;

    private Work() {}

    private static void startProcedure() {
        isRunning = true;
        //<some code>
    }

    private static void stopProcedure() {
        //<some code>
        isRunning = false;
    }

    //------Public API

    public static void start() {
        processor.execute(startQuery);
    }

    public static void stop() {
        processor.execute(stopQuery);
    }

}
```

Comment: if only those `stop`/`stop` funcs update that `isRunning`, then marking the var as `volatile` would be enough **if and if** the update is `direct-set`, and not `read-update`.